# How can I compare times (expressed as minutes and hours) correctly?

Tags: python

```
current_hour = 12
current_minute = 37
current_section = "PM"
due_hour = 9
due_minute = 0
due_section = "AM"
```

Given the current time and deadline time represented by the
variables above, determine if an assignment is still eligible
for submission. An assignment is eligible if the time
represented by current_hour, current_minute, and
current_section is before the time represented by due_hour,
due_minute, and due_section.

my code is

```
total_min_cur=((current_hour*60)+current_minute)
total_min_due=((due_hour*60)+due_minute)
print((total_min_cur<=total_min_due)  and (due_section >= current_section) )
```

We tested your code with due_minute = 0, current_hour = 12, current_minute = 37, due_section = "AM", due_hour = 9, current_section = "AM". We expected your code to print this:

True

However, it printed this:

False

Comment: As shown the first two lines of your code are irrelevant, neither of the variables they update is used in the `print` statement.  I haven't a clue what you expect.

Comment: Please edit the title to explain what you are asking - this will make your question searchable (by some keywords more meaningful than "what's wrong"). E.g., how to compare times (expressed as minutes and hours) correctly? (choose the wording that best suits what you actually want).

Comment: I want   to check if I can submit the assignment I.e the due time is still greater than the current time

Comment: Uhhh maybe because `current_section`'s supposed to be `'AM'` instead of `'PM'` (as it is in your code) ?

Comment: i wrote this logic and on edx plat form and they tested it  and gave the output, is my logic correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert the solution in 24 hour clock and then compare the result.
When both due_section and current_section are equal for your case. Your program will be correct for all total_min_cur and total_min_due until 11:59. After that your program is considering total_min_cur > total_min_due but in actuality it is reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Kunal is correct. 12:01 AM is much earlier than 1:01 AM on a clock. In military time it's 00:01 versus 01:01. Here's what you should do to account for that.

```
total_min_cur = (current_hour % 12) * 60 + current_minute
total_min_due = (due_hour % 12) * 60 + due_minute
print(current_section < due_section or (current_section == due_section and current_time < due_time))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help to solve it

```
current_hour = 12
current_minute = 37
current_section = "PM"
due_hour = 9
due_minute = 0
due_section = "AM"
if current_section=="AM" and current_hour==12:
    current_time_24=0+current_minute
    # print(current_time_24)
elif current_section=="AM":
    current_time_24=current_hour*60+current_minute
    # print(current_time_24)
elif current_section=="PM":
    current_time_24=(current_hour+12)*60+current_minute
    # print(current_time_24)

if due_section=="AM" and due_hour==12:
    due_time_24=0+due_minute
    # print(due_time_24)
elif due_section=="AM":
    due_time_24=due_hour*60+due_minute
    # print(due_time_24)
elif due_section=="PM":
    due_time_24=(due_hour+12)*60+due_minute
    # print(due_time_24)

print(current_time_24<due_time_24)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all `current_hour<=due_hour` -> `12<=9` is `False`
and you are using `>=` to strings. `AM` is not greater than `PM`(on alphabetical ordering). So `False and False` is `False`
Second you are comparing strings that is dangerous, because:

```
In [1]: "am" < "pm"
Out[1]: True

In [2]: "am" < "Pm"
Out[2]: False
```

You should do this `print((total_min_cur>total_min_due)  and (due_section < current_section) )` and you will get `True`.
Change `due_section` and `current_section` to something useful like enumerative , object or a boolean (es: `morning=True` ).
Or atleast do convert to the same case `s.lower()`

Comment: I thought AM and PM are inbuilt functions, at first I used == but after running it I changed it to >=   P.S: can I use only logical operators and variables, mathematical operators to solve this?

Comment: Yes you can, but it is difficult to read for others :). You can use  logic operands if you change `current_section` to `current_section.lower() `, same for `due_section `, if you can't do that you can assume that your input is uppercase (or lowercase). Remember that you can use De Morgan law for change `and` to `or` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws.